# Multiport connection between home router and switch for better LAN bandwidth

Tags: networking, router, lan, switch, gigabit-ethernet

I have quite a few GigE devices at home that I’d like to have better LAN speed between them, but at the moment, all I have available are 3 ports on my (GigE) FTTH router (It has 4 but can’t use one of them, it's a pass thru port).

If I buy a 16 port GigE switch and connect the 3 available ports in my router to the switch, would this provide the switch with 3Gbit available for the remaining 13 ports? I mean, sort of like having a switch with a 3Gbit backplane?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately without a switch and router that support bonding the connections all you'd create is duplicate network traffic and a very slow network. I've actually had a client who accidentally did this with 2 ethernet cables and the result was very slow network connectivity across the entire network. Is there a reason you want 3Gbs of connectivity to your router? I'm assuming you don't have a 3Gb internet connection. A good GigE switch will not route any local traffic to the router so you should have 1Gb / port of connectivity across the LAN.

Comment: It's not that I have a 3Gbps internet access (200Mbit, though), but I have like 6 different GigE ethernet devices that I'd like to have them all connected in my LAN at the best speed possible. I kinda knew this was not possible without channel bonding/aggregation or trunking, but I somewhat expected someone with a brilliant solution or something. I guess I'll have to buy two 4 port switches for a decent solution. Thanks for your answer anyway.